# How to embed language in Sitecore-uCommerce nice URLs?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore-ucommerce

I am using the default configuration of uCommerce and see that uCommerce nice URLs are not language aware: http://sitename/catalogname/productname/c-XX/p-YY.

What should I do to have language in those URLs like this: http://sitename/en/catalogname/productname/c-XX/p-YY ?

Here is the configuration:

```html
<linkManager defaultProvider="sitecore">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="sitecore" type="Sitecore.Links.LinkProvider, Sitecore.Kernel" addAspxExtension="false" alwaysIncludeServerUrl="false" encodeNames="true" languageEmbedding="always" languageLocation="filePath" lowercaseUrls="true" shortenUrls="true" useDisplayName="true" />
  </providers>
</linkManager>
```

Here is how I use it:

```cs
public WebshopProduct Map(UCommerceProduct uProduct)
{
    ProductCatalog catalog = CatalogLibrary.GetCatalog(25);
    IUrlService urlService = ObjectFactory.Instance.Resolve<IUrlService>();
    ...
    var url = urlService.GetUrl(catalog, uProduct) // this returns "/catalogname/productname/c-XX/p-YY"

    //And I would like to have "/en/catalogname/productname/c-XX/p-YY"
}
```

Comment: I think that it is not uCommerce specific issue. You should be able to set up languageEmbedding="always" to your link manager in configuration.

Comment: It's already the case, but it does not embed it.

Comment: Can you give an example how you are rendered links on your website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I have come up with:

```cs
public static class TemplateIDs
{
    // sitecore/ucommerce item's template id       
    public static ID UCommerce => new ID("{AABC1CFA-9CDB-4AE5-8257-799D84A8EE23}");
}

public static class ItemExtensions
{
    public static bool IsUCommerceItem(this Item item)
    {
        var items = item.Axes.GetAncestors();
        return items.Any(x => x.TemplateID.Equals(TemplateIDs.UCommerce));
    }
}

public static string GetItemUrlByLanguage(Sitecore.Globalization.Language language)
{
    if (Context.Item.IsUCommerceItem() && SiteContext.Current.CatalogContext.CurrentProduct != null && SiteContext.Current.CatalogContext.CurrentProduct.Guid == Context.Item.ID.Guid)
    {
        ProductCatalog catalog = CatalogLibrary.GetCatalog(25);
        IUrlService urlService = ObjectFactory.Instance.Resolve<IUrlService>();
        var url = "/" + language.CultureInfo.TwoLetterISOLanguageName + urlService.GetUrl(catalog, SiteContext.Current.CatalogContext.CurrentProduct);
        return url;
    }
    else
    {
        //Normal URL creation
        using (new LanguageSwitcher(language))
        {
            var options = new UrlOptions
            {
                AlwaysIncludeServerUrl = true,
                LanguageEmbedding = LanguageEmbedding.Always,
                LowercaseUrls = true
            };
            var url = LinkManager.GetItemUrl(Context.Item, options);
            url = StringUtil.EnsurePostfix('/', url).ToLower();
            return url;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As a side note you still have a hardcoded "/" in there. In my experience it's best to avoid that and use the stringutil or Sitecore.Mvc.Extensions.StringExtensions (WithPostfix, WithoutPostfix, WithPrefix,WithoutPrefix) to ensure you have the URL part you need.

Answer (score 0):

Adding language to URL depends on how you are rendered links. If you don't pass specific parameters than Sitecore (and uCommerce as part of Sitecore) uses LinkManager configuration sitecore>linkManager>providers: languageEmbedding adn languageLocation attributes. You should have languageEmbedding="always" and languageLocation="filePath"

P.S.
But, be aware if you using their demo or something based on their demo(e.g. from certification courses): they uses regular ASP.Net MVC(not Sitecore MVC). And links are not rendered via LinkManager and you should put language to URL by youself. Register routed with language code that is embedded to them.

Comment: You are right about Item's URL. If I use LinkManager to create links, i have the language embedded. But then my URLs are Sitecore-like: http://sitename/en/sitecore/ucommerce/products/2/26/productname. This is not what I need. Besides, I have document not found on them, because these are uCommerce items. 

So I need to use UrlService.GetUrl(). It gives nice uCommerce URL but without language.